# When I load data form my DB it says "Path contains an empty part", how should I adjust the code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can loop out every table from my DB except this particular one for some reason. When I launch my app it crashed immediatly with this error "Path contains an empty part" as I am initializing my "retrieve-the-data" function directly. So this is how I loop it out, I get the results in the log just fine.

```
    foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {

                theName = currentItem ["name"].ToString (); 
     }
```

and then I have tried to solve it by doing something like this:

```
     if (Path != null) { //when I try to solve it like this then I get the error: System.IO.Path is a type but a variable was expected.

      //i work with pins and the pins are alrdy added just fine. it is just this code below that is the issue.

      pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding (theName));
      pin.BindingContext = theName;
      //this is where I get the error/crash. if I write my own text, for example "test" instead it runs and also if i do pin.Label = theName; So the setbinding/bindingcontext does not seem to like the data iam trying to connect it with.

     }
```

when I loop out the results in the log I get every item perfectly fine so i reach the data I retrieve the data and the info I am receiving is standard text, with "", dots, etc.

When i google the matter and the issue in particular "Path contains an empty part" i see no previous threads. So I am very confused right now.

This is how I retrieve the data via httprequests:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getInfo ()
{
    var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

    var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("localhost");

    var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

    var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

    return jsonResult;

}
```

Comment: `Path` is referring to the type `System.IO.Path` which is not a variable. It is generally not a good practice to name variables after classes in the system libraries. You need to use a different variable name than `Path` above, and that will solve the first error. I don't really understand your other errors - when/where do you see "Path contains an empty part"?

Comment: When I launch my app it crashed immediatly with this error "Path contains an empty part" as I am initializing my "retrieve-the-data" function directly. And this is the "issue". The Path != null is just me trying to solve it somehow and Path is not a variable btw. I used the System.IO.Path but obviously that did not seem to work out

Comment: Are you using SQLite as the DB? Where are you initializing the "DB"? Can you post that code? Can you post the stack trace for this crash?

Comment: I use phpmyadmin and i retrieve the data via httprequest. I updated the code with how i retrieve the data. What is stack trace and where can I find that, in the log?

Comment: I get every other "table" in the db just fine. It is just this particular table that gives me this error.

Comment: How about the stack trace for the error? It would help if you knew which line of code caused the issue. Is it in the parsing? During the request? When reading the content of the response? Or somewhere else entirely?

Comment: It is "label.text = theName;" in this case. When I try convert the info from the DB into my label/my list/pin. I can retrieve the data and post it in the log just fine.

Comment: as Dylan suggests, you need to look at the stack trace to figure out what code is throwing the underlying exception.  Trying to fix it without knowing that is pointless.

Comment: I know it is this line: ""label.text = theName;" but i do not know how to see at what "point" of the process it crashes. are there any good links where i can read about stack trace for ios?

Comment: It should be printed in the output window on Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio.

Comment: updated the post with the correct info i think

Comment: is that what you are looking for? i cannot understand much of those lines to be honest

Comment: can u tell what is the issue with what i updated the post with? or did i look in the wrong output?

Comment: I think you're on the right track but that's not quite what I need. Are you using Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio? The stack trace should include the message from the exception (the "Path contains an empty part" text). It sounds like the problem is in the code that sets the text on the Label. What is the actual text that it is using? If you set the label to that same text in a hard coded string, does the error occur? This seems quite strange.

Comment: What you posted in the application output, not the stack trace.

Comment: I am using xamarin studio and forms. Oh ok. Sorry. I know what the issue now and I didnt think that would be the issue so I did not mention it. I use a `pin.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, new Binding (theName));
        pin.BindingContext = theName;` and this is what makes it crash. When I load the data as `pin.Label = theName` it works so there is defnititly the setbinding/bindingcontext that is the issue. if i write my own text into the binding it works as well, so the setbinding/bindingcontext does not seem to like the data i am trying to connect it with.